# TemplateSyntaxError despite name defined?

Tags: django, django-templates

I have the following line in `urls.py`:

```
url(r'^changepassword/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.password_change',
    {'template_name': 'account/changepass.html', 
     'post_change_redirect' : reverse('settings')}, name='change_password'),
```

However, when loading a different view (with a link to this url) I get a `TemplateSyntaxError`:

> ## TemplateSyntaxError at /account/
>
> Caught NoReverseMatch while rendering: Reverse for 'change_password' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.
>
> `In template ..../templates/account/settings.html, error at line 7`
>
> `<p><a href='{% url change_password %}'>Change your password</a>`

What could be going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't use `reverse` in code that is executed before the url config has been loaded, for example in `settings.py`, or in your case, the url config.

As of Django 1.4, you can use [`reverse_lazy`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#reverse-lazy) instead of `reverse` in these cases.

Answer (score 0):

Removing the `reverse` call and changing it simply to `/settings/` fixed this. I'm not sure why `reverse` is not working here.

Answer (score -1):

Try: `<a href='{% url "change_password" %}'>` (with the name in quotes - `change_password` should be a string, not a template variable)

Comment: -1 Not until Django 1.5, or unless OP is using `{% load url from future %}`

Comment: @supervacuo: who says the OP *isn't* using `{% load url from future %}`? Your comment is warranted; the downvote is not.

Comment: I'm happy to turn the -1 into a 0 and even a +1 if @Timmy updates the answer. Until then, it's an incorrect statement about the `{% url %}` tag; a perfect use for -1

Comment: I'm not really here to beg for your upvotes. It's entirely possible that the OP is using `future` and it's good practice either way to make the distinction between strings and template variables

Answer (score -1):

You can use like this: `{% url django.contrib.auth.views.password_change %}`

Comment: Try use reverse_lazy instead reverse.